# Receive rtsp stream using gstreamer

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, video-streaming, gstreamer

I want to receive rtsp stream using gstreamer I knw rtspsrc can be used for this purpose but the problem is that it only receives it as a client but in my case i have a ffmpeg application which streams the video as a client and waits for a server to connect with it before streaming. So i want gstreamer to act as server and receive the stream from ffmpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it myself, but I believe there is a separate package for RTSP server functionality.  In Debian based systems it should be under something like:

libgstrtspserver-0.10-0